# How can I restrict CREATE TABLE access for a user to a specific schema (sql server)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, create-table

I'd like to allow some users to create tables in a particular schema, but not be able to create tables in other schemas. How can I achieve this?

I see the [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28SQL.90%29.aspx) help says

> Requires CREATE TABLE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the table is being created.

Does that mean I can give ALTER permission to the schema and restrict ALTER permissions on all other schemas?

Comment: Sure sounds like that it what it means... wouldn't take more than a few minutes to try it out either?

Comment: @Klaus: I agree, I sometimes wonder why people post questions to the internet while it would be a lot quicker to simply try things out - just like in this case...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's about helping other people as well. I just came to this question/answer via a google search and it's exactly what I needed. Thumbs up from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes.

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO SomeUser
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::AllowedSchema TO SomeUser
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::RestrictedSchema TO SomeUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set user to schema owner